# Partial sum difference bounded by convering sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $ p \in \mathbb{Z^+} $, and $b_n$ a monotone-decreasing sequence approaching $0$.
>
> Given $|S_{n+p} - S_n| \leqslant b_n$, prove that the series $S_n$ is convergent

I managed to prove that the statement above is correct (see proof below), but after talking with some classmates I am not so sure, as they all believe the statement is incorrect.

**Proof**

Given $b_n$ monotone decreasing, and approaching $0$, we can conclude that $ b_n \geqslant 0 $.

Using the definition of limits for a series, we can say that:

$$ \forall \varepsilon_1 > 0: \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n > N_1 : |b_n - 0| = b_n < \varepsilon_1 $$

Now, because we know that $|S_{n+p} - S_n| \leqslant b_n$ we can then directly say that for all $n > N_1: |S_{n+p} - S_{n}| < \varepsilon_1$, and using [Cauchy's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test) we can conclude that the series $S_n$ converges. $ \blacksquare $

Is my proof correct? If not, what is my error? I appreciate help.

Comment: It depends. In the premise of the question, if the inequality holds for all $p$, then your proof is correct. On the other hand, if $p$ is a specific positive integer where the inequality holds, then the proof is incorrect.

Comment: I understand that, this is also what I was talking with my classmates. The question isn't in English, and translated, it says "Let p be some natural number".